# How to get gnatmake to create a mapfile for an Ada .dll?

Tags: dll, gnat, map-files

So, I am trying to get gnatmake to give me a map file for a dll I am building.

But it i resisting every effort to do so. --create-map-file is only for executable, and it does make one for that, but I cannot get it to take for a .dll.

I have tried -M  --print-map    -M save.map
but I am not getting anything to come out.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to build the DLL using [`gnatdll`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Building-DLLs-with-gnatdll.html#Building-DLLs-with-gnatdll). Here's a (very simplistic) example (without initialization/finalizing code):

**Makefile**

```
all:
    gnatmake -v demo.adb
    gnatdll -v -d demo.dll .\demo.ali -largs -Wl,-Map,demo.map
```

**demo.ads**

```
package Demo is

   function Add (X, Y : Integer) return Integer
     with Export, Convention => C;

end Demo;
```

**demo.adb**

```
package body Demo is
   
   ---------
   -- Add --
   ---------
   
   function Add (X, Y : Integer) return Integer is
   begin
      return X + Y;
   end Add;

end Demo;
```

**demo.def**

```
LIBRARY   LIBDEMO
EXPORTS
    add
```

**output** (directory contents after build)

```
demo.adb
demo.ads
demo.ali
demo.def
demo.dll
demo.map         <<<<<<  A .map file
demo.o
libdemo.dll.a
Makefile
```